# Murmur Hash - Hash values not consistent

Tags: c++, hash

I implemented MurmurHash in C++ and it hashes fantastically except that if you call it twice in a row with the same string... it doesn't hash to the same number. 
Why is it not hashing to the same number all the time???

```
int 
Hash::hf (string ins) {
  return MurmurHash2(&ins,ins.size(),11); 
}
unsigned int Hash::MurmurHash2 (const void *key, int len, unsigned int seed )
{
// 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
// They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.
const unsigned int m = 0x5bd1e995;
const int r = 24;

// Initialize the hash to a 'random' value

unsigned int h = seed ^ len;

// Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash

const unsigned char * data = (const unsigned char *)key;

while(len >= 4)
{
    unsigned int k = *(unsigned int *)data;

    k *= m; 
    k ^= k >> r; 
    k *= m; 

    h *= m; 
    h ^= k;

    data += 4;
    len -= 4;
}

// Handle the last few bytes of the input array

switch(len)
{
case 3: h ^= data[2] << 16;
case 2: h ^= data[1] << 8;
case 1: h ^= data[0];
        h *= m;
};

// Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
// bytes are well-incorporated.

h ^= h >> 13;
h *= m;
h ^= h >> 15;

return h % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your code that's hashing the same string twice and printing different numbers?

Comment: Because you're passing address to `string` with implicit conversion to `void*` - pass `string::data()` instead.

Comment: Abyss does this mean that it is using the strings pointer rather than the data to do the hash? Can you explain what changes I need to make to pass the string data instead?

Comment: `return MurmurHash2(ins.data(),ins.size(),11);`

Comment: What you are hashing is the internals of the string and depending on the length you pass, random memory beyond that.  If you want to hash the actual string, pass it to the function `MurmurHash2(ins.c_str(), ins.size(), 11);`  `ins.data()` cand be used instead of `ins.c_str()` if your compiler supports that.

Comment: Your `Hash::hf()` function should probably take a `const string &ins`, and should probably pass `ins.c_str()` to the Murmur hash function.

Comment: Not passing a reference combined with the incorrect usage is likely why the hash was different each time since each string was a new copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
return MurmurHash2(&ins,ins.size(),11);
```

Correct code:

```
return MurmurHash2(ins.c_str(),ins.size(),11);
```

But, I want to say, this murmur seems like relative weak function, and can produce collisions with much more highest probability, than a random.
Let you see: If on the any iteration, block of lowest bits of "h" becomes zero, then these bits will not be changed after

```
h *= m;
```

Also, because of used XOR in next operation, doubled values will XOR-out from hash.
So, even number of repeating of 4-byte substring, like "abcdabcd" would not change low-bits of hash, too.

Comment: You wouldn't always want a random hash. Murmur is useful for applications like bloom filters, where you want a relatively quick function, that gives you the same hash when you pass it the same value. It's not meant as a cryptographic hash and shouldn't be used as one.